# Dialogs using ActionBarSherlock/HoloEverywhere Light

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using Christophe Versiuex's [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) library project and the `Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock` theme.

The system dialog boxes - copy all text, date picker dialog, etc - all have white text as the window title rather than the light blue. You can see this if you run the demo.

I've tried styling them using `android:windowTitleStyle` but with no luck. Is anyone using this and found a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I am Christophe! Working on these dialogs is really hard for me, and I really hope to find an answer to this question soon. Any idea is welcome, because this issue is really making my lib nearly unusable in a Light theme.Thank for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

The title text is [hard to change](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/280#). You can change the background color for the title so it becomes readable, and leave everything else in the light theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" 
       parent="Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.DarkActionBar.Sherlock">
       <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialogHoloMix</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogHoloMix" 
       parent="AlertDialogHoloLight">
       <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/dialog_top_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

I tested this on Gingerbread and ICS.